# FFMPEG and validating command

Tags: php, ffmpeg, compression

I'm using ffmpeg with PHP to compress the size of some videos I upload on my website, but I also want to capture the error If something goes wrong during the process when executing the command.

I have read that there's no way to capture the error, but I'm not sure if that's correct.

I hope someone will help me out with this doubt I have.

Here's my code:

```
$command="$ffmpeg -i $video['tmp_name'] -i pics/watermark.png -s $resolution -filter_complex [1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(127/60)*ih/10/sar:ih/10[wm][base];[base][wm]overlay=10:10 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy videos/$video_name";

shell_exec($command);
```

Comment: Try `$shellOutput = shell_exec($command);`

Comment: Check out [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php). It is more verbose and complicated, but gives you access to stderr